# Java Hashtable.contains() error

Tags: java, hashtable

I am using the latest version of Java for x64.

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

I found out that the Hashtable has undesired behavior. Here is a snipped code example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable<MyObject, MyObject> table = 
            new Hashtable<MyObject, MyObject>();

        MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
        System.out.println(myObj.hashCode());
        System.out.println(myObj.equals(myObj));

        if (!table.contains(myObj)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
            table.put(myObj, myObj);
        }

        if (!table.contains(myObj)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            System.out.println(table);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1500
true
OK
ERROR
{"myObject"="myObject"}
```

Any clue how come it behaves that way? Can someone point to the problem? By the way, when I am doing the same using HashSet(), I do not get the undesired effect.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Hashtable instead of [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)/[`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? _Edit_ it looks like you're really looking for [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)/[`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Comment: Any details about MyObject class?

Comment: How is `MyObject` implemented? Specifically how is `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented?

Comment: @Matt HashMap is unsynchronized

Comment: @MarvinLabs which part is relevant?

Comment: Use `ConcurrentHashMap` for a multithreading-friendly collection. There is almost never a compelling reason to use `Hashtable` anymore. But seriously, it looks like you're really looking for a `Set` implementation.

Comment: How did you compare `Hashtable` and `HashSet`? One is a `Map` and the other is a `Set`, they don't do the same thing! Also `Hashtable.contains()` is equivalent to `Map.containsValue()`, while **usually** you'd use `containsKey()` more often.

Comment: @Matt I look for Hashtable. I do not need multithreading collection, I only have random access to the Hashtable, hence it has to be synchronized.

Comment: ***WTF*** unless the collection might be accessed by multiple threads, you don't need any sort of synchronization or concurrency.

Comment: @Matt. containsKey(); that is the answer! SHAME ON ME, HAIL YOU. how do I mark this thread as solved?

Comment: You can add your own answer, and accept it when the site will let you (there's a minimum time limit).

Comment: Shouldn't contains() work as well, because the value is in the map?

Comment: @Justin - yes, it should and it does... works fine for me, I could not reproduce the above behavior.  Need to see `MyObject.equals`...

Comment: @Carlos myObj.equals(myObj) prints out as true, and returns a hashCode() value of 1500.  Somethings just not right.

Comment: @Justin - agreed, something is not right, but it still works for me (as expected). `Hashtable.contains()` loops over all elements and uses `equals` to compare the value of each entry with the object being searched; `hashCode` is not involved at all. Or it is not the standard `java.util.Hashtble`, or `equals` is not always returning true, or the `Hashtable`s content is being manipulate elsewhere, or ...

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable works just fine but is undesirable was replaced by HashMap in Java 1.2 (1998) I suggest you not use it unless you have to.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Hashtable<MyObject, MyObject> table =
            new Hashtable<MyObject, MyObject>();

    MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
    System.out.println(myObj.hashCode());
    System.out.println(myObj.equals(myObj));

    if (!table.contains(myObj)) {
        System.out.println("OK");
        table.put(myObj, myObj);
    }

    if (!table.contains(myObj)) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        System.out.println(table);
    }
}

static class MyObject { }
```

prints

```
1584673689
true
OK
```

however a better solution would be to use a Map like HashMap.